# Why product is not showing in Magento front end in 1.9

Tags: magento, admin

I installed fresh Magento 1.9 after adding category and product.Product is not showing in front end.I set product in stock its status to enables,quantity to 100.In root category set Is Anchor to yes,Clear cache and index.But still product is not showing in front.

Comment: Did you check visibility?

Comment: its Catalog, Search.

Answer (score 1):

- By Default, Magento products are "Out of Stock". In admin section, **catalog-> Manage Product -> select your product(click on it)-> Inventory -> Stock Availability -> Make "In Stock".**
- Set **Genneral -> Product status -> enable**
- Check in product in category : **categories->select categories**

Answer (score 0):

Try to reindex all.
Just go to System -> Configuration -> Index Management select all and click reindex.

Comment: As i explained above I did all the possible solution available in stack over flow.Please suggest other than that.

Answer (score 0):

Using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0. Go to Manage Products->select the product->Inventory. Set the stock quantity to some value, and set Stock Availability to "In Stock".